# Unable to update mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a weird issue that is baffling me. I have a model:

```
var Model = new Schema({
    name: String,
    variations: Array
});
```

The variations entry looks like this:

```
[ {code: '', price: '' }, {code: '', price: '' }]
```

I need to add a new field - say "color". So I am doing this to batch update:

```
Model.find().exec(function(err, products) {
    if (!err) {
        products.forEach(function(p) {
            for(var i = p.variations.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                p.variations[i]['color'] = 'red';
                // This shows all existing variations 
                // with the new color feed - correct
                console.log(p.variations[i]);
            }
            p.save(function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log("Success");
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });     
    }
});
```

However the "color" field is not set - if I go through again and comment out the `p.variations[i]['color'] = 'red';` line then it does not show. I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this. I have an onSave event that is triggered correctly so it's saving. I also do not have any check on the variations structure - i.e. there is no code that only allows code and price.  I'm obviously missing something but after a couple of hours I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you modify the contents of an untyped `Array` field like `variations`, you need to notify Mongoose that you've changed its value by calling `markModified(path)` on the modified document or a subsequent `save()` call won't save it. [See docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

```
  for(var i = p.variations.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    p.variations[i]['color'] = 'red';
  }
  p.markModified('variations');
  p.save(function(err) { ...
```

Comment: This is also true if you use any deep objects with a loosely-typed schema (mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed). And as of Mongoose 4.5.8, the above method (markModified) is still a working method to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the **[set](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-set)** function to change a property. The reasoning behind that is that mongoose has to mark the field as modified in order to be saved to the database.

```
for(var i = p.variations.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
  p.variations[i].set({"color":"red", "code":"herr"});
  // or
  p.variations[i].set("color":"red");
  p.variations[i].set("code":"herr");
}
```

An alternative would be to change the field's value the old way, without going trought the setter, then manually mark it as modified: `p.markModified('variations');`

In my opinion you should always use the setter since this is more readable. You can just pass a json object containing all your changes in parameter and it will safely update the fields that you *really* want to change.