# Fail to insert JSON into mongoDB using mongoose in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I am failing in updating my mongoDB using mongoose in node.js

This is my schema:

```
var bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
content: JSON,
views: Number,
name: String,
genre: String,
Description: String,
dateOfCreation: Date,
published: Boolean
})
```

so 'content' is a JSON element. 
In a previous query I insert into 'content' the following JSON:

```
{
    "author": "AuthorName",
    "series": "SeriesNameIfPartOfASeries",
    "name": "NameOfBook",
    "page": []
}
```

My problem is that I am failing in updating the db after editing the JSON.

I am trying to add this into the array of pages:

```
{
"img": "urlOfImage",
"frame": [{
    "id": "0",
    "cx": "0",
    "cy": "0",
    "scale": "1",
    "rotation": "0",
    "filters": "",
    "transition":
        {
            "type": "move",
            "time": "0",
            "easing": "linear"
        },
    "requireUserInput": "true",
    "cropping":
        {
            "visible": "false",
            "shape": "rect",
            "color": "rgb(0,0,0)",
            "opacity": "1",
            "x": [],
            "y": []
        }
}]
```

}

for some reason the following code does not throw any errors, but is not updating the db.
Also, if I console.log(b.content) within the b.save() function, it seems to have updated it but my db remains unchanged.

```
    function (req,res) {
    Book.findOne({_id: req.body.bookID, _creator: req.user._id },function (err, b) {
        if (err)
            throw(err)
        var page = {
            "img": req.files.file.name,
            "frame": [{
                "id": "0",
                "cx": "0",
                "cy": "0",
                "scale": "1",
                "rotation": "0",
                "filters": "",
                "transition":
                {
                    "type": "move",
                    "time": "0",
                    "easing": "linear"
                },
                "requireUserInput": "true",
                "cropping":
                {
                    "visible": "false",
                    "shape": "rect",
                    "color": "rgb(0,0,0)",
                    "opacity": "1",
                    "x": [],
                    "y": []
                }
            }]
        }
        b.content.page.push(page)
        b.save(function (err) {
            if(err)
                throw(err)
        //the following returns the book WITH the right data. What is going
        //on?
        console.log(b.content)
        })
    }
```

**Edit 1:**
**--------------------------------------**

Tried using markModified() still doesn't work. Here is my updated code with suggested solution:

```
    function (req,res) {
        Book.findOne({_id:req.body.bookID, _author: req.user._id},function(err,b) {
            if(err)
                throw(err);
            if(b) {
                var page = {
                    "img": req.files.file.name,
                    "frame": [{
                        "id": "0",
                        "cx": "0",
                        "cy": "0",
                        "scale": "1",
                        "rotation": "0",
                        "filters": "",
                        "transition":
                        {
                            "type": "move",
                            "time": "0",
                            "easing": "linear"
                        },
                        "requireUserInput": "true",
                        "cropping":
                        {
                            "visible": "false",
                            "shape": "rect",
                            "color": "rgb(0,0,0)",
                            "opacity": "1",
                            "x": [],
                            "y": []
                        }
                    }]
                }
                b.content.page.push(page)
                b.markModified('content')
                b.save(function (err) {
                    if(err)
                        throw(err);
                })
            }
        })


    res.end('200')
}
```

Comment: Is there a version mongoose that has a JSON type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to update mongoose model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076317/unable-to-update-mongoose-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the save() method, sometimes Mongoose doesn't know that something has changed. You can use the markModified() to mark the array as having been modified:

```
b.content.page.push(page);
b.markModified('content');
b.save(function (err) { .... })
```

Comment: I tried it (see edit). It still doesn't work. What could it be?