# Mongoose - array value is not over overwritten on save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Getting a bit desperate on this. The code finds a user by a hash. On the returned model i change some values and save it. All properties get changed in the db, however the array item [0] of parent.tree_data.total_children.level remains unchanged, although it changes in the model when I execute the script, however, in the db it does not change. Any ideas?

```
      var parent = await utils.findUser(hash);   //returns mongoose model

      ... code in between where I use values from the parent doc ...

      //updating the parent doc via the model
      parent.tree_data.parent_tag = "dev";
      parent.tree_data.total_children.level[0]++;
      parent.tree_data.direct_children.push({share_hash: result.share_hash, nicname: result.nicname});
      parent.val = parent.val + 0.4;

      parent.save(function(err){
        if (err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
```

scheema part for tree_data looks like this:

```
tree_data: {
    parent_tag: {type: String},
    parent_share_hash: {type: String, required: false, trim: true},
    direct_children: [{share_hash: {type: String, required: true, trim: true}, nicname: {type: "string", trim: true} }],
    total_children: {level: [Number]},
},
```

Comment: Have you defined level sub object in your model?

Comment: edited to add scheema

Comment: in the db level is listed as type "Array"

Comment: interestingly: when i add: parent.tree_data.total_children.level.push(212341234); that element will show up in the db.

Comment: when inspecting the element: just before the .save, parent.tree_data.total_children.level looks like this:
0:1
1:212341234
2:212341234

in the db it looks like this:
0:0
1:212341234
2:212341234
this is crazy

Comment: is increasing in the model property and there is a value 0 in the db.

Comment: To reveal the issue might you try that level[0] = level[0]+1

Comment: also tried ... it just ignores changes to .level[0]

Comment: seems I can push but I cant change any element of that array this way.

Comment: So how to I manage to do it?

Comment: Javascript allows to update number array element by using ++ notation. It might be related Mongoose. You might open an issue on Mongoose github page. I cannot find any other option for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call `markModified` on the element as arrays (or objects, mixed types, etc) are not marked automatically when their content changes.

Have a look at [Unable to update mongoose model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076317/unable-to-update-mongoose-model)

```
  parent.tree_data.parent_tag = "dev";
  parent.tree_data.total_children.level[0]++;
  parent.tree_data.direct_children.push({share_hash: result.share_hash, nicname: result.nicname});
  parent.val = parent.val + 0.4;


  parent.markModified('tree_data.direct_children'); // if that doesnt work, try: paremt.markModified('tree_data')


  parent.save(function(err){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

Comment: thanks!
parent.markModified('tree_data.direct_children'); didnt work, but 'tree_data' worked.
'tree_data.direct_children.level' or even 'tree_data.direct_children.level[0]' also didnt work.

Comment: I think thats an issue, think even overwriting the whole level array of the model obj with another one did not make it beeing changed in the db